# phpPgAdmin - log in works but I have to login again after clicking on any links

Tags: nginx, centos, postgresql-9.6, phppgadmin

I have setup Postgres 9.6 and phppgadmin on a Centos 7 server with nginx,

I can log in to phpPgAdmin, however PostgreSQL server on the right of the page remains crossed out and any link I try to browse to (databases, roles etc) requires I log in again.

I'm thinking this seems like a sessions problem, but I am unsure as to how to resolve it.

Any pointers on how to fix or what I should be looking at in order to track down the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

turns out owner of /var/lib/php/session was apache - needed to be nginx.

sorted by changing ownership to nginx as below:

chown -R nginx:nginx /var/lib/php/session/